# How to make lesskey terminal-independent?

Tags: less

In bash scripts we can use `tput` to set terminal-independent less variables:

```
export LESS_TERMCAP_me=$(tput sgr0; )
```

Can we do the same thing with `lesskey`?

Answer (score 3):

### Short answer

- **Yes** you can put variable `LESS_TERMCAP_me` in the `lesskey` file but it requires fixing the source code and building your own `less` version (I explain that below).
- **No** the `lesskey` file cannot contain external commands as `tput` to become terminal-independent. However, you may use several `lesskey` files as recommended by the [Thomas Dickey's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/342576/13999).

### `lesskey` file

The command [`lesskey`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/lesskey.1.html) is used to convert a human-readable text content into a binary configuration file for command `less`. This configuration file is named *`lesskey` file* and is usually the file `~/.less`.

This files contains three sections:

1. **Command** (e.g. `:q quit`)
2. **Line editing** (e.g. `^G abort`)
3. **`less` environment variables** (e.g. `LESS_TERMCAP_me = \033(B\033[m`)

### Put variables `LESS_TERMCAP_*` in the `lesskey` file

```
$ cat > lesskey.txt << EOF
#env
LESS = -iSrsM +Gg
LESS_TERMCAP_md = $(tput bold; tput setaf 6)
LESS_TERMCAP_me = $(tput sgr0)
LESS_TERMCAP_so = $(tput bold; tput setaf 3; tput setab 4)
LESS_TERMCAP_se = $(tput rmso; tput sgr0)
LESS_TERMCAP_us = $(tput smul; tput bold; tput setaf 7)
LESS_TERMCAP_ue = $(tput rmul; tput sgr0)
LESS_TERMCAP_mr = $(tput rev)
LESS_TERMCAP_mh = $(tput dim)
EOF

$ lesskey lesskey.txt  # By default lesskey writes ~/.less

$ man bash             # By default man uses less (pager)
```

### Bug

The command `less` reads the configuration `~/.less` too late:
just after searching for variables `LESS_TERMCAP_*`.

This bug affects [version 487](http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/news.487.html) released on 29 Mar. 2017 (and surely previous versions).

I have just sent a bug report and the corresponding fix to maintainers. I will update this answer when the fix will be applied for the next `less` release...

### Fix it yourself

1. Download source code archive from:

   - upstream: http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/download.html
   - GNU ftp server: http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/less/?C=M;O=D
   - a mirror server: http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/less/
2. Inverse two lines in file `main.c` at line 113
   Before:

   ```
   /*
    * Process command line arguments and LESS environment arguments.
    * Command line arguments override environment arguments.
    */
   is_tty = isatty(1);
   get_term();
   init_cmds();
   init_charset();
   init_line();
   ```

   After:

   ```
   /*
    * Process command line arguments and LESS environment arguments.
    * Command line arguments override environment arguments.
    */
   is_tty = isatty(1);
   init_cmds();         /* Load lesskey file before */ 
   get_term();          /* getting variables LESS_TERMCAP_* */
   init_charset();
   init_line();
   ```
3. Install dependencies required for the build

   ```
   ./configure
   ```

   If `./configure` fails, identify the missing dependencies.
   In my case I have installed `ncurses-devel` to get header `term.h`.
4. Build

   ```
   make
   ```
5. Keep your own-compiled `less` somewhere, for example to a personal directory `~/bin`

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/bin
   cp ./less ~/bin
   PATH="$PATH:~/bin"
   ```

   Do not forget to set the environment variable `PATH` in your `~/.profile` or if you prefer any other file as `~/.bashrc`, `~/.login`...

### Extra tips

- See the `TERMCAPS` used in a man-page

  ```
  LESS_TERMCAP_DEBUG=1 man bash
  ```
- Retrieve the man-page with `TERMCAPS` encoding

  ```
  MANPAGER='tee man.txt' man bash
  ```
- Combine these two tips

  ```
  MANPAGER='tee man.txt' man bash
  LESS_TERMCAP_DEBUG=1 less man.txt
  ```

Comment: `lesskey` is for *function-keys*.  This answer is relevant only for adjusting video-highlights.

Comment: Hi @ThomasDickey. Thank you for checking new answers and for your feedback. The command line `lesskey` is used to store *commands* and *variables* in a configuration file for command `less`. I am pretty sure the OP requests how to put the environment variables `LESS_TERMCAP_*` within the `lesskey` file. Please read the section **Put your variables `LESS_TERMCAP_*` in the lesskey file** within my answer to understand what I mean. Please advice me what you suggest I can do to improve my answer. Cheers

Comment: manual page says "lesskey - specify key bindings for less"

Comment: Yes @ThomasDickey, you are right, but it is also for the environment variables used by `less`. The `lesskey` file has three sections: **Command** (e.g. `:q quit`), **Line editing** (e.g. `^G abort`) and the **`less` environment variables** (e.g. `LESSCHARSET = latin1`). Do I miss-understand something? Cheers

Comment: Hi @ThomasDickey. I think I understand what you mean: the OP has requested a solution to have a **terminal-independent** `lesskey` file. And your answer explain how to manage multiple `lesskey` files depending on the targeted terminal. Therefore I have updated my answer and created a link to your answer. Am I correct? Cheers

Comment: Less has been updated to 530

Answer (score 0):

You can make `less` read a different `lesskey` file for each terminal type, e.g., by setting the `LESSKEY` (or `LESSKEY_SYSTEM`) environment in your shell initialization.  The simple way of doing that would be to use the `TERM` variable as part of the filename, and making your shell check for the existence of these terminal-dependent files before setting the `LESSKEY` variable.