# Why the LESS_TERMCAP settings does not work when put it into ~/.profile

Tags: shell, zsh, login, startup, less

I have the following LESS_TERMCAP settings:

```bsh
# less config
export LESS=-R         
export LESS_TERMCAP_mb=$'\E[01;31m' # begin blinking
export LESS_TERMCAP_md=$'\E[01;31m' # begin bold    
export LESS_TERMCAP_me=$'\E[0m' # end mode          
export LESS_TERMCAP_se=$'\E[0m' # end standout-mode
export LESS_TERMCAP_so=$'\E[01;44;37m' # begin standout-mode
export LESS_TERMCAP_ue=$'\E[0m' # end underline
export LESS_TERMCAP_us=$'\E[01;33m' # begin underline
export LESSOPEN='| /usr/bin/highlight -O ansi %s 2>/dev/null'
```

When I put into `~/.profile`, the less viewer gets absolutely messy. On the other hand, when I put into `~/.zshrc` (I am using `zsh`), it works, why?

Since I was taught to keep the environment variables into non-login shell config files, such as `~/.profile`, I want to do so.

Further information:

```
 tapyu@tapyu-ThinkPad-P73
 OS: Ubuntu 20.04 focal
 Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.13.0-28-generic
 Uptime: 2h 25m
 Packages: 2559
 Shell: zsh 5.8
 Resolution: 2048x1152
 DE: GNOME 3.36.5
 WM: Mutter
 WM Theme: Adwaita
 GTK Theme: Yaru-dark [GTK2/3]
 Icon Theme: Yaru
 Font: Ubuntu 11
 Disk: 123G / 217G (60%)
 CPU: Intel Core i7-9750H @ 12x 4.5GHz [43.0°C]
 GPU: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
NVIDIA Corporation GP107GLM [Quadro P620] (rev a1)
 RAM: 4740MiB / 23681MiB
```

Best regards.

Comment: Probably the shell that's used for `.profile` doesn't understand the syntax (which is not all that old - ymmv).

Answer (score 1):

Check the value of the `LESS_TERMCAP_xxx` variables:

```
print -lr ${(q)LESS_TERMCAP_mb}
```

(Or, if not using zsh: `echo "$LESS_TERMCAP_mb" | od -tx1c`)

Chances are that, as Thomas Dickey guessed, you'll see `\$\\E\[01\;31m` rather than `$'\033'\[01\;31m` (`$ \ E [`… rather than `033 [`…). This happens if `.profile` is invoked by a shell such as dash which doesn't understand the `$'…'` syntax. `/bin/sh` is dash on many popular distributions including Ubuntu.

One solution is to use another way of representing the escape character. You can use `printf` to generate it portably:

```
esc=$(printf \\033)
export LESS_TERMCAP_mb="${esc}[01;31m" # begin blinking
…
```

Alternatively, define these variables in your `.zshrc`. This has the advantage of letting you customize their content based on the terminal's capabilities. And then you may want to call `tput` instead of hard-coding escape sequences. ([Documentation on LESS_TERMCAP_* variables?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108699/documentation-on-less-termcap-variables) may help.)

Alternatively, define these variables using [lesskey](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/lesskey.1.html), which writes them into less's configuration file (`~/.less`). This makes more sense than putting them in the environment if you always set them to the same value, since [they're a configuration of `less` specifically](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108699/documentation-on-less-termcap-variables). However, [this doesn't work in older versions of less](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/328597/how-to-make-lesskey-terminal-independent).

Comment: 1. I am using Ubuntu 2. `/bin/sh` is a symbolic link to `dash`, indeed 3. the command `print -lr ${(q)LESS_TERMCAP_mb}` prints `$'\033'\[01\;31m`, which contradicts your statement

Comment: Honestly, I didn't see any advantage of using `tput` as it has weird-looking commands, just as the escaped command does...

Comment: your alternative to use `esc=$(printf \\033)` didn't work. It didn't make the less messy, but it didn't colorize properly either...